# how to draw text on a memory buffer

Tags: winapi, window

I want to draw some text on a memory buffer, but don't know how to. please help, many thanks!
 Code:

```
 widht = 640;
 height = 480;
 pBuf = malloc( width * 3 * height );

 memset( pBuf, 0, width * 3 * height );

 //DrawText is the function that needs to be implemented, and I don't know how to do it.
 DrawText( "this is the text that i want to draw on the buffer", pBuf, width, height, 3 );

 //now there is text on the memory buffer pointed to by pBuf.
```

Comment: Do you mean just copy that string into `pBuf`? If so, just `memcpy()` or `snprintf()`.

Comment: A memory buffer containing what? If it's a bitmap/DIB, then you'll need to either get the existing DC, or create a DC/bitmap with that data and draw to that.

Comment: 1. Draw the text on the buffer, like displaying the text on the buffer, not just copy the string.

Comment: 2. it's a memory buffer, and you can call it a DIB. "create a DC/bitmap with that data and draw to that" sounds like the answer to my question, but could anybody explain it in more details? How do I create a DC/bitmap with that data?